# Using unpack() to convert to a byte array in PHP

Tags: php, python, binary

I'm trying to convert a binary string to a byte array of a specific format.

Sample binary data:

```
ê≤ÚEZêK
```

The hex version of the binary string looks like this:

```
00151b000000000190b2f20304455a000003900000004b0000
```

The Python script uses `struct` package and unpacks the above string (in binary) using this code:

```
data = unpack(">hBiiiiih",binarydata)
```

The desired byte array looks like this. This is also the output of the `data` array is:

```
(21, 27, 0, 26260210, 50611546, 912, 75, 0)
```

How can I unpack the same binary string using PHP's `unpack()` function and get the same output? That is, what's the `>hBiiiiih` equivalent in PHP?

So far my PHP code

```
$hex = "00151b000000000190b2f20304455a000003900000004b0000";
$bin = pack("H*",$hex);
print_r(unpack("x/c*"));
```

Which gives:

```
Array ( [*1] => 21 [*2] => 27 [*3] => 0 [*4] => 0 [*5] => 0 [*6] => 0 [*7] => 1 [*8] => -112 [*9] => -78 [*10] => -14 [*11] => 3 [*12] => 4 [*13] => 69 [*14] => 90 [*15] => 0 [*16] => 0 [*17] => 3 [*18] => -112 [*19] => 0 [*20] => 0 [*21] => 0 [*22] => 75 [*23] => 0 [*24] => 0 )
```

Would also appreciate links to a PHP tutorial on working with pack/unpack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This produces the same result as does Python, but it treats signed values as unsigned because `unpack()` does not have format codes for signed values with endianness. Also note that the integers are converted using long, but this is OK because both have the same size.

```
$hex = "00151b000000000190b2f20304455a000003900000004b0000";
$bin = pack("H*", $hex);
$x = unpack("nbe_unsigned_1/Cunsigned_char/N5be_unsigned_long/nbe_unsigned_2", $bin);

print_r($x);
Array
(
    [be_unsigned_1] => 21
    [unsigned_char] => 27
    [be_unsigned_long1] => 0
    [be_unsigned_long2] => 26260210
    [be_unsigned_long3] => 50611546
    [be_unsigned_long4] => 912
    [be_unsigned_long5] => 75
    [be_unsigned_2] => 0
)
```

Because this data is treated as unsigned, you will need to detect whether the original data was negative, which can be done for 2 byte shorts with something similar to this:

```
if $x["be_unsigned_1"] >= pow(2, 15)
    $x["be_unsigned_1"] = $x["be_unsigned_1"] - pow(2, 16);
```

and for longs using

```
if $x["be_unsigned_long2"] >= pow(2, 31)
    $x["be_unsigned_long2"] = $x["be_unsigned_long2"] - pow(2, 32);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about negative numbers. Shouldn't `$x["be_unsigned_long2"] ` be equal to `$x["be_unsigned_long2"] - pow(2-32)`?